# Jupyter Notebook does not import any module

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-18.04, python-module

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c1d07d468637> in <module>
----> 1 import requests
      2 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

- I first installed a module and was wondering why it was not working.
- Then I tried with modules that ought to be installed, like pandas and requests.
- On all modules, I get the same issue.
- Then I checked if the modules really are not installed, or if they are not in the proper folder
- After that, I uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda

Nothing worked so far. I appreciate any help

Jupyter error message:

[image: Jupyter error message]

Pip installed modules:

[image: Pip installed modules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are installing your modules on a vitualenv and the Jupyter notebook is running outside the virtualenv.

This happened to me once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to append the path to your modules to sys.path.

Example from within your notebook, if u want to import some selfwritten module from some relative location:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../../")
sys.path.append("../../")

# Rest of your code goes here, for example import $MODULE_NAME
```

Then you can `import $MODULE_NAME` (so, use the proper modulename of your desired module) iff. that module is in `../../` or in `../../../`.

HTH. :-)